# Kryonet - double incoming packets

Tags: kryo, kryonet

Okay. I am receiving packet once, but it's block is fired twice. For example:

I have a block like this:

```
           if (object instanceof InitTheGame) {
                System.out.println("STARTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT");
                awaitOpponent.dismiss();
                isInQueue = false;
                matchRunning = true; // handles the while loop inside the thread that sends data to the server
                isInMatch = true; // handles view (checks for this if we exit the app)
                // new GamePacketSender().start();
                casualGameHolder.gameLoop.start();
                new Sensor(act, casualGameHolder.gameLoop);
                touchListener = new TouchListener(casualGameHolder.gameLoop);
                this_layout.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);

                act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        GameStartCountdown countdown = new GameStartCountdown(4000,1000);
                        countdown.start();
                        countdownDialog = new Dialog(act);
                        countdownDialog.show();
                        countdownDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    }
                });
            }
```

In console (LOG_TRACE) I can see, that the packet was received ONCE, but the "STARTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT" System.out is shown twice, countdown is shown twice etc.

I don't want to post the whole code, cause it's huge and hard to understand. May this caused by overflowing the buffer on the server, or maybe by this that I have SOMEHOW two connections opened at the same time on one device? If there is any experienced person with Kryonet, I would be grateful for help.

Comment: Can you show the code where you send the data from the Server to here.

Comment: The problem was cause of two listeners opened. I didn't remove the listener after completing a game - it was creating a new one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caused by registering multiple listeners (should be null after the game is complete).